# How to fix syntax error: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.'

Tags: c#, sql, windows-forms-core

```
cmdUpdate.CommandText = "UPDATE Products2 " +
                " SET ProductName = '" + txtProductName.Text + "', " +
                " Description = '" + txtDescription.Text + "' , " +
                " Quantity = '" + txtQuantity.Text + "' , " +
                " CriticalLevel = '" + txtCriticalLevel.Text + "' , " +
                " PurchasePrice = '" + txtPurchasePrice.Text + "' , " +
                " SellingPrice = '" + txtSellingPrice.Text + "' , " +
                " ProductStatus = '" + cboStatus.Text + "' , " +
                " Created = '" + dtpCreated.Value.Date.ToString() + "' , " +
                " LastModified = '" + dtpLastModified.Value.Date.ToString() + "' , " +
                "WHERE (ProductNo=" + txtProdNo.Text + ");";
```

How do I fix this code?

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.'

Comment: Use SQL parameters

Comment: And take a look at command text generated from your code.

Comment: Try printing `cmdUpdate.CommandText`. You will find the issue.

Comment: [Why is SQL injection still a thing?](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2020/07/16/back-to-basics-sql-injection/)

Answer (score 1):

The smallest problem you have is that last comma before the `WHERE`.
The larger one is the huge security hazard caused by concatenating user input into your SQL statement.
Instead, use parameters. That will also make your code much more readable:

```cs
cmdUpdate.CommandText = "UPDATE Products2 " +
                " SET ProductName = @ProductName, " +
                " Description = @Description, " +
                " Quantity = @Quantity, " +
                " CriticalLevel = @CriticalLevel, " +
                " PurchasePrice = @PurchasePrice, " +
                " SellingPrice = @SellingPrice, " +
                " ProductStatus = @ProductStatus, " +
                " Created = @Created, " +
                " LastModified = @LastModified" +
                " WHERE ProductNo = @ProductNo);";

// Note: I'm assuming SqlServer and also the type and size of the columns.
// Change it to match your actual needs.
cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add(@ProductName, SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = txtProductName.Text;
cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add(@Description, SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = txtProductName.Text;

// and add all other parameters as well
```

[Why is SQL injection still a thing?](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2020/07/16/back-to-basics-sql-injection/)